# SPQuery not returning expected results

Tags: caml

I am trying to filter a SPListItemCollection with CAML but I don't get the results I want.

Here is my code:

```
query.Query = "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + project.Split('/')[1].ToString().Trim() + "</Value></Eq>";
ProjectsList.GetItems(query)[0][Variables.externalProjectNumber].ToString();
```

This should return one item as Title field is unique. However, when I use SP Caml Query Helper, I get all items returned. When I execute the code in Sharepoint, I get an error that a field is not correctly installed.

Anybody see a problem with my code?

Comment: You are missing the `<Where>` clause around your `<Eq>` tags

Comment: I already tried that but got the same behavior. grrrr sometimes I hate sharepoint :(

Comment: ok I managed to get it working so far so I don't get the error anymore even when executing code through sharepoint. but  I still get all items returned even though the column I am querying is unique...

Comment: also tried with <View> tag, same problem persists...

Comment: Use U2U caml builder. You have options to see the CSOM/SSOM code for that query. It always works.

Comment: hmmm weird if I execute it through U2U CAML Builder it works. When I use SP CAML Query Helper it returns too many rows. I will deploy and see what happens.